# when we need chmod +x file.py

Tags: python, permissions, chmod

i wrote a py script to fetch page from web,it just read write permission enough,so my question is when we need execute permission?

Comment: possible duplicate of [review file permissions concept in the UNIX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12754748/review-file-permissions-concept-in-the-unix)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's required to do so if you need to run the script in this way: `./file.py`. Keep in mind though, you need to put the path of python at the very top of the script: `#!/usr/bin/python`.

But wait, you need to make sure you have the proper path, to do that execute: `which python`.

Comment: i'm under ubuntu lucid 10.04,use komodo edit,when i create a py file,it will give a shebang like,#!/usr/bin/env python
is there sth different with #!/usr/bin/python what's common way?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429511/why-do-people-write-usr-bin-env-python-on-the-first-line-of-a-python-script). `#!/usr/bin/env python` is more common.

Answer (score 6):

Read/write is enough if you want to run it by typing `python file.py`.  If you want to run it directly as if it were a compiled program, e.g. `./file.py`, then you need execute permission (and the appropriate hash-bang line at the top).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to run it directly with `$ file.py` then you'll need the execute bit set. Otherwise you can run it with `$ python file.py`.