# review file permissions concept in the UNIX

Tags: unix, ubuntu

the umask is set to 022 and the created files permission would be -rw- r-- r-- which is 644.
the I made a file in this way

```
echo date > date.sh
./date.sh
```

after running the code I will get the error permission denied but if I call the file by using sh command

```
sh date.sh
```

it works.

I have started practicing UNIX recently and was wondering why it happens.

Comment: There is no `-x` executable bit set for any user which is why you can't call it as such `./date.sh`.  Unix won't know what type of executable it is without the shebang line, i.e. `#!/bin/sh`.

Comment: @squiguy: While the shebang is definitely good practice, it's actually not requisite to run a shell script.

Comment: @David I guess I was just used to that with Perl! But yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've not set the executable bit, so UNIX won't run the file. The `sh` utility is executable, however, and can execute the contents of `date.sh` regardless of its permissions.

You can set the file as executable with: `$ chmod +x date.sh`

Observe the permissions of `date.sh` with `$ ls -l`, and you'll see that it's now executable for everyone (`-rwxrwxr-x`).

Comment: you are right, then what is the point if I can execute a file without -x by using "sh" command? if the file permission is set to 644 then it is supposed to be a non executable file. this part makes me confused

Comment: Well, "non-executable" doesn't mean that there's no possible way to execute the contents of a file. There are myriad ways to execute a given set of commands that extend beyond simply executing the file that contains them. However, you'll notice that `/bin/sh` has its own set of permissions. If a user has no execute permissions on `sh` or other system binaries, they won't be able to run your file... unless you explicitly give them permission to. There are too many uses of file permissions to explain here, but trust me- the executable bit is helpful. I suggest you do some more reading!